# Matching Method return type to class in Java?

Tags: java, generics

I need to match method returned type to class. How can I do that?

```
public class MethodTest {

    public static List<String> getStringList()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        for(Method method : MethodTest.class.getMethods())
        {
            Type returnType = method.getGenericReturnType();
            // How can for example test if returnType is class List?
        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but "instanceof" might be applicable:  http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you can check for the `Type` being a `ParameterizedType` and use the raw type if so:

```
if (returnType instanceof ParameterizedType)
{
    System.out.println("Parameterized");
    ParameterizedType parameterized = (ParameterizedType) returnType;
    System.out.println(parameterized.getRawType().equals(List.class));
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Not parameterized");
    System.out.println(returnType.equals(List.class));
}
```

This will cope with `List<?>` and `List`, but it *won't* match methods declared to return a concrete implementation of `List`. (Use `isAssignableFrom` for that.)

Note that missingfaktor's answer is a good one if you're not going to use anything else about the return type's generic type arguments etc.

Answer (score 3):

If you are not interested in `List`'s type parameter, you can just use `method.getReturnType().equals(List.class)` to test if the method returns a `List`.

However note that this will return `false` if the method in question happens to return a subtype of `List`. (Thanks @cHao for pointing that out!) If you want that case to be taken care of, use `List.class.isAssignableFrom(method.getReturnType())`  instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can check like this:

```
if(returnType instanceof List) {

}
```

Comment: No. `obj instanceof cls` is how `instanceof` works. What OP needs is to compare two `Class` objects.

Comment: I understand this question is.  How can for example test if returnType is class List? This what I think he wanted to know.If that is the case , this is true.

Comment: @Unni: Thing is, returnType is an instance of `Class` or `Type`, not an instance of the method's return type.  `instanceof` wouldn't do what you expect.  (ie: `returnType instanceof Class` or `returnType instanceof Type` (depending on which method you use to get the return type) would return true, while `returnType instanceof List` would be false.)